# VSTS Test Agent & Controller 2012 Compatibility

Tags: testing, load-testing

We are mixing devs with VS2010 and VS2012 because all our projects have not been migrated yet.

We already have a complete test rig including a test controller, some test agents and a result repository.

From VS 2012, it is impossible to run remote testing because of a version mismatch. No problem with upgrading it but will my VS2010 tests still be runnable ? beacause I don't want to maintain 2 test rigs and I find it completely useless.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for futures references, there is no compatibility between the two versions. VS2012 requires a 2012 test Controller  (which require 2012 test agents). We also can not install both version on the same machine.